# Elliptic boundary condition eigenvalue problem

Tags: operator-theory, riemannian-geometry, differential-operators, spin-geometry, elliptic-operators

In Chapter 1, section 1.5 of "The Dirac Spectrum" by Nicolas Ginoux, different elliptic boundary conditions for Dirac operators are introduced. On page 24, there is the following theorem

> **Theorem 1.5.2** Let $(M^n, g)$ be a compact Riemannian spin manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial M$. Let $B$ be an elliptic boundary condition for $D$. The the following eigenvalue problem
>   $$ D\phi = \lambda \phi \text{ on } M, \text{ } \text{ } B(\phi|_{\partial M}) = 0 \text { on } \partial M.$$
>   has a discrete spectrum with finite dimensional eigenspaces in $C^{\infty}(\Sigma M)$ [smooth sections of a fixed spinor bundle over $M$], unless the spectrum is $\mathbb{C}$ itself. Moreover, if $B$ is self-adjoint, then the Dirac spectrum is real.

Here, $\Sigma M$ is the spinor bundle associated with a fixed spin structure over $M$. $D$ is the Dirac operator defined by composition of the Clifford multiplication and the compatible connection. My question is the following:

- Why is the self-adjoint condition of $B$ is needed here so that the Dirac spectrum is real? Certainly if certain $(\lambda, \phi_\lambda)$ is a solution, necessarily by the above theorem $\phi_\lambda \in C^{\infty}(\Sigma M)$. And using the $L^2-$formally self-adjoint property of $D$, can we just conclude that
  $$ \lambda ||\phi_\lambda||^2 = \langle D \phi_\lambda , \phi_\lambda \rangle = \langle \phi_\lambda, D\phi_\lambda \rangle = \overline{\lambda} ||\phi_{\lambda}||^2,$$
  which implies that $\lambda$ has to be real? What part is wrong in my argument?